# Beamer and alternative hyperref (with pdftex driver) configurations

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I would like to use a range of 4 to 5 different version of beamer configuration to have a certain flexbility when gerating slides w.r.t. differnt purposes --- e.g. presentation mode, handout, for me, for the web, etc.

So far I had this:

```
% presentation mode
%\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

% handout mode
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=UseThumbs, pdfpagelayout=SinglePage, bookmarks=true, },handout,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

% prepare mode
%\documentclass[notes, hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

% dev mode
%\documentclass[notes, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
```

I enable/disable the one I want when generating a set of slides based on the purpose.

Now, I also want to control my author name, the presentation title and the tags etc for all of those modes --- but, at a single point in the .tex document. I found this information about how to configure the hyperref package (with pdflatex as a driver).

```
% configure hyperref
\usepackage[pdftex,
    pdfauthor={Bill Miller},
    pdftitle={Some Important Title},
    pdfkeywords={tag1, tag2, tag3},
    colorlinks
]
{hyperref}
```

However, they seem not to work well together. I put the usepackage statement at the beginning of the .tex document. I would like to put general settings in the \usepackage{hyperref} statement and add additional configuration parameters in the specific modes (or overwrite them with other settings, e.g. pdfpagemode).

Is this the way to do it? Maybe I am thinking to complicated...

Is it also possible to generate all 4 PDFs in one compilation run with PDFLaTeX?

---

### EDIT

Based on the discussion below I made an update. This is the code I have currently:

```
% presentation mode
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\title{Hypersetup (with PDFLaTeX) and Beamer}

\begin{document}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={Bill Meyer},
    pdftitle={The Meaning of Everything},
    pdfkeywords={world, meaning, everything},
    colorlinks
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}
    \framesubtitle{Test Subtitle}
    This is a test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The Author name and the keywords do not appear in the PDF file, the title is taken from the title tag. Where can I find this information if not in the document properties of the pdf file? Am I doing this right?

Comment: Perhaps trivial, but did you try `\hypersetup` after the `\documentclass` line (`beamer` automatically loads `hyperref`).

Comment: This method seems to work. So, it seems that I have to make one full blown \hypersetup with repeating parameters for each mode? Is there a way to stack these configurations (i.e. defaults (name, title) first, then adaptations (specifics for presentation mode, like fullscreen or not) ?

Comment: You miss my point: `\hypersetup` can come after the various `\documentclass` lines to contain the common set up for all cases.

Comment: I made an edit to the main question to clarify further and to point out that it seem not to have the desired effect. Thanks Joseph for helping me with this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Move `\hypersetup` with `pdfauthor` and friends *before* `\begin{document}`.
- The title is overwritten by `\title`, but you can use `\texorpdfstring` there:

  ```
  \title{\texorpdfstring{Hypersetup (with PDFLaTeX) and Beamer}{%
    The Meaning of Everything}}
  ```

  Or option `usepdftitle` can be set to false, then `beamer` does not use the title of `\title` for the PDF title:

  ```
  \documentclass[..., usepdftitle=false]{beamer}
  ```

Comment: Sounds quite like a hack. Is there any cleaner approach?

Comment: @RalfB Using the same title or option `usepdftitle=false`.